# html css align text such that text is always on right of the image not below it

Tags: html, css, alignment

html css align text such that text is always on right of the image not below it.Thanks for the help!Css for img1 is down below.

[image]

```
  <img id="img1" src="../images/1.jpg">
 <div style="box-shadow: 0 0 15px #666;">
 <p style="text-align: justify;height: auto;min-height: 280px;font-  family: sans-serif,monospace;padding:10px;padding: 10px;box-shadow: 0 0 15px #666;font-size: 20px;color: #000;">
   <br>A photovoltaic system for residential, commercial, or industrial energy supply consists of the solar array and a number of components often summarized as the&nbsp;balance of system&nbsp;(BOS). The term originates from the fact that some BOS-components are balancing the power-generating subsystem of the solar array with the power-using side, the load. BOS-components include:<br>
    Power-conditioning equipment and 
    Structures for mounting, 
    Typically one or more DC to&nbsp;AC&nbsp;power converters, also    known    as&nbsp;inverters,
   An energy storage device, 
   A racking system that supports the solar array, 
   Electrical wiring and interconnections, 
   Electrical protection devices and 
   Mounting for other components.

   Optionally, a balance of system may include any or all of the    following:&nbsp;
   renewable energy credit&nbsp;revenue-grade meter,&nbsp;  
    maximum power point tracker&nbsp;(MPPT),&nbsp;
   battery&nbsp;system and&nbsp;charger,&nbsp;
    GPS&nbsp;solar tracker,&nbsp;
    energy management software,&nbsp;
    solar irradiance&nbsp;sensors,&nbsp;
    anemometer, or 
    task-specific accessories 

    designed to meet specialized requirements for a system owner</p>
```

```
 #img1 {
box-shadow: 10px 10px 50px #333;
float: left;
height: 280px;
margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
max-width: 300px;
width: 240px;
```

}

Comment: code only contains text. Where's the image part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex` property for this, or you can set `width` for image container and text container(and of course, `float` property):

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
}
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="box-shadow: 0 0 15px #666;" class="main-container">
<div class="image">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="" >
</div>

 
  
  
  
  <div class="text-container">
  <p style="text-align: justify;height: auto;min-height: 280px;font-  family: sans-serif,monospace;padding:10px;padding: 10px;font-size: 20px;color: #000;">
A photovoltaic system for residential, commercial, or industrial energy supply consists of the solar array and a number of components often summarized as the&nbsp;balance of system&nbsp;(BOS). The term originates from the fact that some BOS-components are balancing the power-generating subsystem of the solar array with the power-using side, the load. BOS-components include:<br>
    Power-conditioning equipment and 
    Structures for mounting, 
    Typically one or more DC to&nbsp;AC&nbsp;power converters, also    known    as&nbsp;inverters,
   An energy storage device, 
   A racking system that supports the solar array, 
   Electrical wiring and interconnections, 
   Electrical protection devices and 
   Mounting for other components.

   Optionally, a balance of system may include any or all of the    following:&nbsp;
   renewable energy credit&nbsp;revenue-grade meter,&nbsp;  
    maximum power point tracker&nbsp;(MPPT),&nbsp;
   battery&nbsp;system and&nbsp;charger,&nbsp;
    GPS&nbsp;solar tracker,&nbsp;
    energy management software,&nbsp;
    solar irradiance&nbsp;sensors,&nbsp;
    anemometer, or 
    task-specific accessories 

    designed to meet specialized requirements for a system owner. 
    </p>
    </div>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the css float property for the image and set the value as 'left'. For example:

```
image{
       float:left;
}
```

Now the text will flow around the image like how you showed in the image.